# Set up variables in a file instead of in a class JAVA

Tags: java

im not sure if the title is correct but currently i have :

```
private String destinationPDF = "D:/Documents/NetBeansProjects/printing~subversion/fileupload/web/resources/pdf/";
public static String destination ="D:/Documents/NetBeansProjects/printing~subversion/fileupload/Uploaded/";
public String fileList = "D:/Documents/NetBeansProjects/printing~subversion/fileupload/web/resources/Directory Files/directoryFiles.txt";
```

These are defined in the class, across 2 class actually, but this is not a perfect situation for me, i want to know is there a way to store the locations in a txt for example and access that ?

Comment: You can use [`Properties`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use the java.util.Properties class.
See the documentation on the [jdk documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html) page.
Here is a sample usage:

```
    Properties prop = new Properties();
    try {
        prop.load(new FileInputStream("config.properties"));
            System.out.println(prop.getProperty("destinationPDF"));
        System.out.println(prop.getProperty("destination"));
        System.out.println(prop.getProperty("fileList"));

    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
```

And here the properties file:

```
# sample properties
destinationPDF=D:/Documents/NetBeansProjects/printing~subversion/fileupload/web/resources/pdf/
destination="D:/Documents/NetBeansProjects/printing~subversion/fileupload/Uploaded/
fileList =D:/Documents/NetBeansProjects/printing~subversion/fileupload/web/resources/Directory Files/directoryFiles.txt
```